# The code is running, but UPDATE statement does not update data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, sql-update

I try to insert data to column `ansatID` in the table shown on the picture.

User has

- to mark a row in `DataGridView`
- insert his ID in the textBox1 on the left
- then press button `Tilføj ansat til vagten`

and his ID should be inserted into column `ansatID` both in `DataGridView` and database.

But the problem is, that data are not inserted into column `ansatID` in database and nor in `DataGridView`, despite the fact that the code is running. I have tried following code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Vagtplan;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        myconnection.Open();

        DateTime id= Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
        SqlCommand AddNumberCommand = myconnection.CreateCommand();
        AddNumberCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.Vagter SET [ansatID] = @ansatID WHERE [Dato] = '" + id + "'";

        AddNumberCommand.Parameters.Add("@ansatID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;

        AddNumberCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myconnection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Du har valgt vagten.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The expected result is that `ansatID` should be inserted both into column `ansatID` in database and in `DataGridView`. The table in database and `DataGridView` on pictures shows actual results.

[image: Picture]

[image: Picture]

Comment: The variable in your WHERE clause can and should be a parameter too.

Comment: You need to ALWAYS use parameters, not just some of the time. You did a great job using a parameter for ansatID, why did you not use one for Dato? The reason it isn't updating your gridview is because you need to bind the grid again.

Comment: When dealing with an updates involving a time component, you may run into issues trying to resolve milliseconds (or smaller increments). Instead have your gird expose a primary key and use that within ADO.NET to perform the update.  You should not need to display the primary key on grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datetime value causes the problem. In your query in where clause the date value does not return any value so update is not done. You can use ToString method of datetime object on your id on the query like below:

```
 AddNumberCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.Vagter SET [ansatID] = @ansatID WHERE [Dato] = '" + id.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'";
```

But you should use parameters to avoid injection attacks. So i recommend you to use below code segment:

```
AddNumberCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.Vagter SET [ansatID] = @ansatID WHERE [Dato] = @value";
AddNumberCommand.Parameters.Add("@ansatID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
AddNumberCommand.Parameters.Add("@value",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=id;
AddNumberCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: DateTime values **Do Not** cause a problem.  The NET DB provider objects are perfectly capable of passing a `DateTime` and storing it to a `Date` column